# Why is post data completely empty posting to CodeIgniter controller via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have read through all of the SO posts about the same issue and have tried them all. Clearly there is still something I am doing wrong. I can log out all of the data right up to the controller. Post data is always completely empty and I'm not sure why.

**jquery**

```
function onDeleteThing(myId, callback) {

    console.log(myId) // 10

    $.ajax({
        'type': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'cache': false,
        'data': {'id': myId},
        'url': '/my-url/delete',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'timeout': 50000
    }).done(function (response) {
        callback(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        // Total fail.
    });
}
```

**controller**

```
public function delete()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        error_log(print_r($this->input->post(), true)); // returns: Array()
        // even using $_POST returns empty array

        // here is an example of how I plan to send the post data to my model          
        if ($this->My_model->delete($this->input->post('data')) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'fail'));
        }
    }
}
```

But still, the problem I am running into is that `$this->input->post('data')` is empty when it gets to my controller.

**EDIT**

I can also see in the network tab:

```
Request Payload
id=10
```

Comment: Your Ajax is expecting a json response, if the server dies not respond with json and valid json at that, the response will simply be empty. Are you sure your function returns valid json? I don't see where it does

Comment: Hi @DelightedD0D, you are correct, I am not returning anything...yet. I am not able to access the post data I am sending to my controller for some reason. At this point, I have no data to send to a model to send a response back to my controller. On a typical form, I would use `myform.serialize()` for the data attribute and all is well. I'm not sure where I'm dropping the ball in this case.

Comment: @Stryner SO OBVIOUS NOW. That was it. I needed to change it to `'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` and all is well. Thank you for your time!  If you post it as the answer I'll check it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're sending contradictory information to your server:

```
ContentType: "application/json"
RequestBody: "id=10" // Not JSON
```

If you don't need to send json, one solution is to simply remove the `contentType` option from your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, since jQuery will set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` by default.

If you do wish to send JSON, then you'll have to convert it to JSON yourself since jQuery is not capable of doing such. One solution would be to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (and to add the necessary polyfill if you need support for IE7 or below).

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'cache': false,
    'data': JSON.stringify({'id': myId}),
    'url': '/my-url/delete',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'timeout': 50000
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!